# How to locate the Country/State error? Which account is the cause?

Tags: error-messages

While in Mass Transfer of Accounts process, I get the following error:

[image]

*Error: There's a problem with this state, even though it may appear correct. Please select a state from the list of valid states.*

The error appears on the New Owner  - If I select a single account to transfer - it's ok, and passes with no errors. So the problem is NOT with the New Owner data.

If I select the CB that marks ALL the 250 accounts to transfer, that's when I get the error.

Is there an available log for that?
I also tried to check the first/last accounts - to try and guess the algorithm of which accounts are transferred first to try and catch the error.

- The accounts to move are from Brazil. In the States and Countries I have the States of Brazil enabled - But hidden. I need to find the specific account that is the error one related to.

Ideas on how to locate it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you don't have a default country set (which could mean it's the lead convert known issue), the error means you have records that

- don't have a state code value
- do have a state text value (the old value the record had before turning on the picklist feature)
- but the state text value doesn't match any integration values

(Did you map any states to "Unknown Value" during state/country picklist setup? That's the most likely cause.)

You have two options: the automatic way is to go to Setup > Data Management > State and Country Picklists, click Convert Now, and go through the mapper again, without mapping anything to "Unknown Value."

The manual way is to run a report on Account to narrow down the records with errors. Set filters:

1. Billing State (text only) not equal to ""
2. Billing State equal to ""
3. Shipping State (text only) not equal to ""
4. Shipping State equal to ""
5. (whatever else you need to narrow down to the 250 Accounts in question)

Set filter logic to ((1 AND 2) OR (3 AND 4)) AND 5

For each of the results make sure that either the State (text only) field is equal to an existing state integration value, or you update the state code field to a valid value.

Comment: Ill say, most states were converted to Unknown - I actually thought that is a valid value.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like known salesforce [issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T19LAAS).

Workaround is to set org's default country to --None-- to avoid the issue.

http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/General-Development/Leads-Conversion-Error-with-Country-State-Picklist-Winter-14/td-p/700259

https://getsatisfaction.com/dbamp/topics/error_when_converting_lead_state_country_picklist_enabled

Comment: Apparently, during the country conversion, some countries did get a state (from the old values) now even that I have the states as hidden - when I need to edit that account - I get an error on this, since the state is hidden. jigidigid bug.

Answer (score 1):

If you've access to Salesforce panel, and in case you don't need this validation, you can simple disable 'State and Country Picklists' add-on by going to: 'Setup -> Administer -> Data Management -> State and Country Picklists'. Or you should set up the proper state mapping in that picklist.

Comment: Thanks, I know this, I am afraid I will loose all data once I disable that. Without disabling, I want to learn of the account that is the problem.

Comment: Yeah, don't do this, since you'll have to re-map all your state/country data (step 3 in the state/country setup).

Comment: Though "Or you should set up the proper state mapping in that picklist," is a good idea, and I included it in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known error with the Country and State picklists. An update suggests it will be fixed in the Spring '14 release.

A free alternative to the Salesforce Country & State picklists is an application called AddressTools, this is available on the AppExchange and you do not need to clean your existing data before implementing.

https://appexchange.salesforce.com/results?keywords=addresstools

Hope this helps